# How to solve the equation $Axe^x - Bx - Ce^x + C = 0$ for $x$ where $A$,$B$ and $C$ are constants?

Tags: functions, numerical-methods

I have tried solving by using Taylor's series expansion for $e^x$ and approximating till the third term of the expansion (i.e. term with power 2). This gave me a quadratic equation which was easy to solve. But I am using the solution of this equation as part of a bigger numerical simulation using Finite Difference method. And the small error due to approximation in the expansion for $e^x$ accumulated over many iterations and gave erroneous results in the end.

So, I need some other way of solving this equation that does not involve approximation.

Comment: you will Need a nmerical method, some sprecial cases can you solve symbolically

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, could you elaborate on this ? I am using the Block Newton method.

Comment: Also, someone told me that the solution for this equation can be given Lambert function. Is this possible ?

Comment: no solution is found in Lamberd function here, try Wolfram alpha

Comment: see here for the Newton method http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1244946907

Comment: As already said in previous comments, no hope to get an analytical solution except if $A=0$. Now, my question : is the solution supposed to be small ? If this is the case, we could probably do better.

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be any value ranging from small to big.. The values for A,B and C will keep changing with every iteration.